# how to only import module if necessary and only once

Tags: python, import

I have a class which can be plotted using matplotlib, but it can (and will) also be used without plotting it.

I would like to only import matplotlib if necessary, ie. if the plot method is called on an instance of the class, but at the same time I would like to only import matplotlib once if at all.

Currently what I do is:

```
class Cheese:
    def plot(self):
        from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
        # *plot some cheese*
```

..but I suppose that this may lead to importing multiple times.

I can think of lots of ways to accomplish only importing once, but they are not pretty.

**What is a pretty and "pythonic" way of doing this?**

I don't mean for this to be "opinion based", so let me clarify what I mean by "pretty":

- using the fewest lines of code.
- most readable
- most efficient
- least error-prone
  etc.

Comment: If a module is already loaded then it won't be loaded again. you will just get a reference to it.

Comment: What you've written above is absolutely the Pythonic way to do what you want.  It will only be loaded once.

Comment: Often, I find myself wanting to not load some modules if the user invoked my program with the options `--help` or `--version` (or similar). This is specially true for larger modules which take some time to load, and which are not needed unless the main program runs. Is there a neater way to load a module than to include `import` in each and every function that uses the module?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a module is already loaded then it won't be loaded again. you will just get a reference to it. If you don't plan to use this class locally and just want to satisfy the typehinter then you can do the following

```
#imports
#import whatever you need localy
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING

if TYPE_CHECKING: # False at runtime
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is an awesome answer. Just one comment: You have a small spelling error which makes the answer a bit awkward to read: You write "If your don't plan..", it should be: "if you don't plan.."

Answer (score 0):

**Optional import in Python:**

```
try: 
    import something
    import_something = True
except ImportError:
    import something_else
    import_something_else = True
```

**Conditional import in Python:**

```
if condition: 
    import something
    # something library related code
elif condition: 
    # code without library
```

import related to one function:

```
def foo():
   import some_library_to_use_only_inside_foo
```

Answer (score -1):

TLDR; Python does so for you already, for free.

Python import machinery imports module only once, even if it was imported multiple times. Even from different files [(docs)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.modules).

The most pythonic way to import something is to do so at the beginning of file. Unless you have special needs, like import **different** modules depending on some condition, eg. platform (windows, linux).

Comment: However, Python *does* import the module at the point in the code where it encounters the `import` statement, not when the module is first being called. This means that you might not always want to load a module. – E.g. if you're loading a module like `mediapipe` (which is somewhat slow to load), you might want to skip that when your program is invoked with the `--help` option (and thus won't perform any mediapipe related functions, but only display some syntax help to the end user).

Comment: What this "not when the module is first called" thing you are talking about? How to "call" module? How to do that (if it is ever possible) without actually importing module?

Comment: Well, technically you wouldn't call the *module,* but some function(allity) within the module: I only intended to state that the module is loaded when its `import` statement is encountered—not at some later point (such as, for example, when you first invoked some functionality from within the module).